# Emacs's run scl before compile command

Tags: emacs, compilation

I need to run `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash` before I compile with `M-x compile`.

How too doo this in emacs. Thank you.

Comment: did you try `scl ... ; make` for `compile-command` if `&&` isn't working

Comment: YES! I've tried almost everything!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add it before the command you're passing to `M-x compile`.  For example, if you're normally using `make` with `M-x compile`, try:

```
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash && make
```

Comment: Try giving this command to `M-x compile`: `scl enable devtoolset-7 make`.

Comment: Doesn't work, guys. The problem with the @picklerick solution is that scl doesn't work with `&&`. I don't know wat is rwong with the @NickD's solution.